# IIS 5.1 ASP.NET MVC Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, iis

I'm trying to debug Facebook API on my local machine. After reading many websites, I realize I need to set up my ASP.NET MVC application to run on IIS instead of Visual Studio 2008 Web Server. I created the virtual directory but I'm getting this error. The program works fine under VS Web Server.

```
The virtual path '/Views/Shared/Main.Master' maps to another application, which is not allowed.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

is `/Views/Shared/` set up as a Virtual Directory in IIS?  Remove that and it should go away.

Comment: I don't have /Views/Shared set up as a Virtual Directory. I read this blog: http://itscommonsensestupid.blogspot.com/2008/11/deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-on-windows-xp-iis.html, but it still doesn't work after adding the mapping in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that any reference to Views/Shared/Main.Master needs to be changed to ~/Views/Shared/Main.Master.

Thanks everyone.